# Blender Surface Roughness

Tags: modifiers, displacement

I'm trying to model a cube with a rough surface on only one side of the cube, while keeping the other sides relatively smooth. I've been looking around, and so far, all I can find is subdividing and then the displacement modifier. I'm pretty new to Blender, and I'm confused as to how I can apply a rough surface ( not just textured with an image - I'd like the cube to physically have those bumps ) to the cube? I can only find tutorials for working with a plane and making it rough via subdivisions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

EDIT: @Carlo, yes it's because I'm unable to pick on of the six faces. Basically what I'm looking to do is to create only one surface of the cube rough, while every other side remains smooth. Does this clarify my question a bit? Sorry about the delay in response!

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you explain why the subdivision+displace workflow doesn't fit your needs? Is it because it makes other faces pointlessly subdivided? Or because you were not able pick one of six faces in the displace modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple:

- You go in edit mode and select desired face.
- Click <kbd>W</kbd>, than select `Subdivide`.
- Either repeat previous step multiple times or on the bottom left part of screen you will see a value `Number of Cuts` that you can adjust to your needs.
- Select the subdividen faces and in `Mesh` tab add a new vertex grop and assign those objects to it.
- Add displacement modifier, select the verex group under it's setting, select texture and adjust values.

Done! ;)

Comment: thank you so much! However, when I go apply the subdivision modifier to get a smoother surface, the subsurf modifier distorts the rest of my cube as well - is there any way to have it just smooth out the one side of the cube? It looks like selecting the "simple" subdivision algorithm, it doesn't distort the shape as much, but it still distorts the sides of my cube a bit?

Comment: Hm... I don't know that much. As I am a game developer, I have not paid much attention to high-poly things.